# rootstrap: command not found

Tags: root, chroot, cgroup

I'm trying create a system-root to do some tests using jail and I'm trying install *rootstrap* whitout success.

```
$ rootstrap
rootstrap: command not found
```

When try install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y rootstrap
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package rootstrap
```

My OS Version:

``````
                    ./+o+-       
                  yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
               ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.4.0-33-generic
           .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 13h 40m
         .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 2190
        o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: bash 5.0.16
       .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Resolution: 1920x1080
  .++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   DE: Xfce
 /+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   WM: Xfwm4
 \+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   WM Theme: Qogir-win-dark
  .++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.   GTK Theme: Qogir-win-dark [GTK2]
       .+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    Icon Theme: Qogir-ubuntu-dark
        \+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     Font: Noto Sans 9
         `:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:      Disk: 17G / 156G (11%)
           .o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`      CPU: Intel Core i7-4790K @ 8x 4.6GHz [28.0°C]
               /osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/     GPU: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB
                   ````` +oo+++o\:     RAM: 5672MiB / 15919MiB
``````

This package was substitute for another?

Comment: What exactly do you need? There seem to be any number of container-based options - systemd-run, docker, lxc, podman, etc. for running commands in a jail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I discovered that Ubuntu uses another commando the `debootstrap` 
And using them I got create the *system-root*.

Like this:

```
sudo debootstrap --arch amd64 focal system-root
```